# nonlinear least squares troubleshooting

Tags: r, regression, nls

I am trying to run a nonlinear least squares regression in R and keep coming across the same error message which I can't seem to fix.

My function so far:

```
nls(y ~ 1033.89+(2461*cos*(2*3.14*(t-18)/24)), 
        data=data.frame, start=list(x=1, y=1))
```

where t=c(1:24) and data.frame contains x and y variables of equal length.

This error message continues to pop up:

> Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) :
>     :2:0: unexpected end of input
>   1: ~
>      ^
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Any suggestions?

Comment: there seems to be some mix up between data and parameters to be estimated. Your starting values suggest the parameters should be  `x` & `y` but they are not in your function and in fact the `y` looks like data (as its on the lhs of the tilde)

Comment: ... `cos*(` isn't correct syntax